# Vertical/Horizontal Alignment in Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am currently working on a call center stat page and am really just getting started in the HTML5/CSS world.  I am having a small(huge to me) problem that has been bugging me for the past two days.  At the top-left of my web page, I am needing the "100%" and "100" to be centered horizontally and vertically.  I have tried several things such as display: table-cell, line heights, and several other things but nothing seems to center my text vertically as well as horizontal.

Here is the JSFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/neggly/ndprc/

**CSS**

```
/*! normalize.css v1.0.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/* ==========================================================================
   HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Corrects `block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section,
summary {
    display: block;
}

/*
 * Corrects `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}

/*
 * Prevents modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/*
 * Addresses styling for `hidden` attribute not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3,
 * and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Base
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * 1. Corrects text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/*
 * Addresses `font-family` inconsistency between `textarea` and other form
 * elements.
 */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*
 * Addresses margins handled incorrectly in IE 6/7.
 */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Links
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Addresses `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/*
 * Improves readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Typography
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Addresses font sizes and margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 * Addresses font sizes within `section` and `article` in Firefox 4+, Safari 5,
 * and Chrome.
 */

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0.83em 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1.33em 0;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 0.83em;
    margin: 1.67em 0;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    margin: 2.33em 0;
}

/*
 * Addresses styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Safari 5, and Chrome.
 */

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

/*
 * Addresses style set to `bolder` in Firefox 3+, Safari 4/5, and Chrome.
 */

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 1em 40px;
}

/*
 * Addresses styling not present in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 */

dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}

/*
 * Addresses styling not present in IE 6/7/8/9.
 */

mark {
    background: #ff0;
    color: #000;
}

/*
 * Addresses margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

p,
pre {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

/*
 * Corrects font family set oddly in IE 6, Safari 4/5, and Chrome.
 */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
    font-family: monospace, serif;
    _font-family: 'courier new', monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/*
 * Improves readability of pre-formatted text in all browsers.
 */

pre {
    white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

/*
 * Addresses CSS quotes not supported in IE 6/7.
 */

q {
    quotes: none;
}

/*
 * Addresses `quotes` property not supported in Safari 4.
 */

q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

small {
    font-size: 75%;
}

/*
 * Prevents `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Lists
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Addresses margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

dl,
menu,
ol,
ul {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

dd {
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

/*
 * Addresses paddings set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

menu,
ol,
ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

/*
 * Corrects list images handled incorrectly in IE 7.
 */

nav ul,
nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * 1. Removes border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improves image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/*
 * Corrects overflow displayed oddly in IE 9.
 */

svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Figures
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Addresses margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Corrects margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/*
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/*
 * 1. Corrects color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Corrects text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Corrects alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/*
 * 1. Corrects font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Addresses margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improves appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/*
 * Addresses Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/*
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Corrects inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improves usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Removes inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/*
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/*
 * 1. Addresses box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Removes excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Removes excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/*
 * 1. Addresses `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Addresses `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/*
 * Removes inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
 * Removes inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * 1. Removes default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improves readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Tables
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* 
    Created on : Apr 3, 2014, 9:37:25 AM
    Author     : meggleston
*/

#wrap {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: black;
}

#statuscolorwrap
{
    background-color: aqua;
    float: left;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
}

#numberwrap
{
    background-color: #ff0;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

#announcementwrap
{
    background-color: coral;
    float: left;
    width: 79%;
    height: 100%;
}

#queuewrapper
{
    height:40%;
    width:100%;
    float: top;
    background-color: darkorchid;
}

#queuecolors
{
    height:40%;
    width:100%;
    float: top;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

#queuepercentage
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: top;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

#queueholding
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: bottom;
    background-color: crimson;
}

#topcolor
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: top;
    background-color: darkseagreen;
}

#bottomcolor
{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: bottom;
    background-color: moccasin;
}

#datetimewrapper
{
    width:100%;
    height:4%;
    float: top;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#messages
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    float: top;
    background-color: darkorchid;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.messagewrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    float:top;
    background-color: azure;
}

.messageimportance
{
    float:left;
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
}

.messagesubject
{
    float:left;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

h1
{
    font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: tab
}

h2
{
    font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: left;
}

h3
{
    font: 30px/50px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

#anpicturewrap
{
    float:top;
    width:100%;
    height:46%;
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

#antextwrap
{
    float:top;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}

h4
{
    font: 20px/100px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

#text
{
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Virginia Summary</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.fittext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="numberwrap">
                <div id="queuewrapper">
                    <div id="queuepercentage">
                        <h1>100%</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="queueholding">
                        <h1>100</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="messages">
                    <div class="messagewrapper">
                        <div class="messagesubject">
                            <h2>Enter Subject here</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="messageimportance">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id ="statuscolorwrap">
                <div id="queuecolors">
                    <div id="topcolor">

                    </div>
                    <div id="bottomcolor">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="announcementwrap">
                <div id="datetimewrapper">
                    <h3>12/12/2014 18:00</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="anpicturewrap">
                    <img src="images/pic.jpg" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div id="antextwrap">
                    <div id="text">
                        <h4>sample text</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("h1").fitText(.3);
            $("#fittext2").fitText(1.2);
            $("#fittext3").fitText(1.2);
            $("#fittext4").fitText(1.2, {minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '30px'});
            $("#fittext5").fitText(1.2);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As stated earlier, I am fairly new to this so any further suggestions are always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following achieved your desired result:

```
#queuewrapper { display: table; }
#queuepercentage, #queueholding { display: table-row; }
#queuepercentage h1, #queueholding h1 { display: table-cell; height: 90px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/ndprc/1/

Comment: I hate how easy you made that look.  This worked perfectly.  Thank you!